# Запустить дистанционно скрипт google colab

Tags: python, telegram, telebot, google-colaboratory

Есть телеграмм бот на python, в который загружают фотку. На этой фотке надо распазновать людей
Есть скрипт, в google colab, который на вход получает фотку и распознаёт на ней людей.

Этот скрипт использует модель (face_toolbox_keras), которая очень много весит, и положить её на хостинг не получается. Лежит она на папке google вместе с colab. Можно ли через python при триггере дистанционно запустить google colab.
Возможно через Google API?

Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего никак. В том смысле, что нет такого функционала.

Но вы можете поднять сервер типа [ngrok.com](http://ngrok.com), и управлять своим содержимым через SSH.

Одним из вариантов такой реализации [demotomohiro/remocolab](https://github.com/demotomohiro/remocolab).

В бесплатном варианте книга может работать до 12 часов. Не забывайте сохранять данные на Диск Гугл или на другой удаленный файловый ресурс.